# Is this proposition true? (Preservation of the behavior of the series)

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Apply the comparison test to determine whether the series $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3n}{\sqrt{n^3+2}}$ is divergent.

I choose the harmonic series to do the comparison through the following relation.

$$ \frac{3n}{\sqrt{n^3+2}} \ge \frac{3n}{\sqrt{n^4}} = \frac{3n}{n^2} = \frac{3}{n} > \frac{1}{n}$$
But then I realized that the first inequality is true $\forall n\ge 2$ and false when $n=1$.
My intuition tells me that if a finite number of terms in the series is altered, its behavior does not change. That is, it remains convergent (or divergent) as well as the original series. In this case, I think I just have to take the harmonic series and the one which I want to test from 2 onwards, right?
My problem Is that I don't really know if that proposition is true or not, despite what my intuition suggest me.

It is true? In that case, how do I prove it?

Comment: What you said is completely correct, only the tail of a sequence matters when you are discussing convergence .. the sum of finitely many terms in a series is finite as well .. ignoring a finite number of terms won't change convergence or divergence of the series (see what happens in both cases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That's true. Let $a_n$ be a sequence defined for $n \ge 1$. Then, for any $p \in \mathbb N$:

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} a_n \text{converges} \iff \sum_{n \ge p} a_n \text{converges}$$

**Proof:**

Let $\{S_n\}$ be the sequence of partial sums associated to $\sum_{n \ge 1} a_n$ and $\{T_n\}$ be that associated to the other one. Note that: $S_n = T_n + (a_1 + \ldots + a_{p-1})$. For simplicity, let $a = a_1 + \ldots + a_{p-1}$, then $S_n = T_n + a$. Where $a \in \mathbb R$.

If $\sum_{n \ge 1} a_n$ converges, then $\{S_n\}$ converges, so $\exists$ $l_1 \in \mathbb R$, such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = l_1$. Then, $\lim_{n \to \infty} T_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (S_n - a) = l_1 - a = l_2 \in \mathbb R$, hence $\{T_n\}$ converges, i.e. $\sum_{n \ge p} a_n$ converges.

I guess that you can do the other one by yourself.

Comment: Could you be a little more detailed on the proof, please?

Comment: @Ygdra: check the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$${3n\over \sqrt{n^3 + 2}} \sim {3\over \sqrt{n}} $$
as $n\to\infty$.  The series diverges by limit comparison with the $p$-series for $p = 1/2$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @ncmathadist: you could simplify a little further by writing the given series is $O(\frac1{\sqrt{n}})$.

Comment: Unnecessary, Bernard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true.

**Theorem** Let $\{a_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $\{b_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be sequences that are eventually equal (i.e. there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{n}=b_{n}$ for all $n\geq N$). Then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}<\infty$ iff $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}<\infty$.

**Proof** Suppose that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}<\infty$. $\sum_{n=N}^{M}a_{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{M}a_{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_{n}$, and so
$$
\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}a_{n}=\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{n=N}^{M}a_{N}=\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{M}a_{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_{n}
$$
The final sum $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_{n}$ is finite, so $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}a_{n}<\infty$.
Since $a_{n}=b_{n}$ for all $n\geq N$, this tells us that $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}b_{n}<\infty$. But $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}=\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}b_{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}b_{n}$ (you can flesh this out a little more, in the manner used above), so $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}$ is just the finite number $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}b_{n}$ plus the finite number $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}b_{n}$ (in particular, it's finite).

On the other hand, suppose that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}$ diverges. If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}$ converges, then by preceding argument (with the roles of the sequences reversed) we could show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges, which contradicts the assumption we just made. So if one series diverges, the other must, as well.